# Custom jQuery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question - is it possible to extend jQuery selectors to change the resultset (for example) via traversal instead of just by filtering an existing set?

To clarify - I don't want the selector equivalent of a call to `$.filter()` - I want something closer to `$('foo:nth-child(n)')` or `$('foo:eq(n)')`, where I can specify exactly which elements are returned by the selector.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Edit: here's an example of what I want to implement:

```
$.expr[':']['nth-parent'] = function(deTarget, iIndex, aProperties, aStack) {
    var iN, $currentElement;

    if(!deTarget)
        return;
    if(!aProperties || aProperties.length < 4 || isNaN(iN = parseInt(aProperties[3])) || iN < 0)
        throw('jQuery.nth-parent(N) requires a non-negative integer argument');

    $currentElement = $(deTarget);
    while(--iN >= 0)
        $currentElement = $currentElement.parent();

    aStack = $currentElement.length ? [$currentElement.get(0)] : [];
    return aStack.length ? true : false;
};
```

So, ultimately, I'd want the new `aStack` array returned as the result set, in this particular case.

Comment: Yes you can extend the selectors, you'll have to provide examples of what you want to select so that we can help show you how.

Comment: "I want something closer to $('foo:nth-child(n)') or $('foo:eq(n)')" - why not just use those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this, a proper example here would be what you're after in the question, here's how [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) is implemented:

```
jQuery[":"].eq = function(elem, i, match) {
   return match[3] - 0 === i;
};
```

The signature has one more parameter, `stack`, like this:

```
function(elem, index, match, stack)
```

`stack` is the set of *all* elements, if you need use that in your filtering.

Comment: Hey Nick - I think I was wrong with `eq`; you can get that information based on the current selector context; I want to return elements out of that context.  See the updated snippet in the question.

Comment: @mway - I think you have your selectors backwards, you're climbing to *get* the `nth-parent()`, this is better done as a function, selectors are *for the current element*.  For example `:nth-child()` selectors elements that *are* the `nth-child`, not that *have* `n-children`, that would be backwards from how CSS selectors work altogether.

Comment: Ah yes, this was a little less about CSS and more about just providing a convenience selector for traversing up the tree.

Answer (score 2):

This link should help you with what you need:
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/custom-jquery-selectors.html

But to answer your question yes it is possible to create custom selectors.

Comment: No - that page shows you how to filter the current result set with a selector, eg, "any element that has a rel attribute" (with respect to that page).  I want to traverse and return elements found (via traversal) with the selector - not filter.

Comment: Ok maybe I am not understanding then. Can you provide a pseudo code example of what exactly it is that you are looking for?

Comment: Have a look at the updated question - maybe that will help clarify... sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want a custom selector with a parameter:

```
$.expr[':'].heightAbove = function(obj, idx, meta, stack) {
    return ($(this).height() > parseInt(meta, 10));
};
```

You can then call this as

```
$('div:heightAbove(40)');
```

to select divs with a height above 40px.