# Cascading calls between custom jQuery selectors - Poor Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery plugin with some custom selectors. In one of the selectors, I want to call another custom selector to filter the results before calling the current one.

So, for example I have `:foo` and `:bar`. Whenever I call `:bar`, I want it to act like calling `:not(:foo):bar`.

I tried writing `:bar` like this:

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    bar: function (element) {
        $(element).not(':foo').hasClass('bar');
    }
    foo: function (element) {
        // Some very time consuming stuff...
    }
});
```

But `:foo` is not very efficient, so I only want to call it a single time during the operation. `jQuery` calls the `bar` function for **every element** that matches the selector that is passed to bar (typically it is called without one, so `*` is what is used), so it takes a long time.

Is there some way to wrap up the call to the `:bar` selector so it automatically applies the `:foo` filter before iterating all of the calls to the `bar` function?

According to the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587327/custom-jquery-selector) and [this post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1457-how-to-build-a-custom-jquery-selector.htm), I should have access to 4 parameters in the selector function (element, index, properties, and stack). I was hoping to grab the stack, do my filter on it, determine if any element has the class, then clear the stack. However, index is always 0 and stack is undefined in `jQuery` 1.10.2.

Are there any other ways of getting this done?

> NOTE: I am looking for a solution that will work in all versions of `jQuery` 1.4.2 and later.

Comment: If an element is `:foo`, you know it's not `:bar`. If you're using the `:foo` selector and the `:bar` selector on the same elements, it could be better to simply select `('.bar')` and filter out the `:foo` elements.

Comment: That would assume that I have control over all of the callers of the selector, but I don't. That is why I am trying to combine them here - the business rule is that `bar` must not include `foo`. `foo` is a user-defined ignore selector, and it is my plugin's responsibility to apply the ignore on `bar`.